# Trying to get property of non-object notices in comment-template.php

Tags: comments, notices, wp-comment-query

I need some customization of WORDPRESS comment area, so I've used this code in my child theme :

```
    <div id="comments" class="x-comments-area">

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

    <?php
    //The author of current post
    $author_ID = get_the_author_meta("ID");
    //The current post ID
    $p_ID = get_the_ID();
    ?>

    <h2 class="h-comments-title"><span><?php _e( 'Comments' , '__x__' ); ?>  <small>
    <?php 
    //Number of guest comments
    echo ztjalali_persian_num(number_format_i18n(count(get_comments(array('post_id' => $p_ID,'author__not_in' => array($author_ID))))));
 ?></small></span></h2>
    <ol class="x-comments-list">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments( array(
    'callback' => 'x_icon_comment',
    'style'    => 'ol'
  ) );
  ?>
    </ol>

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="visually-hidden"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', '__x__' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', '__x__' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', '__x__' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
    <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' , '__x__' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
//Loading of smilies
    ob_start(); cs_print_smilies(); $cs_print_smilies = ob_get_clean();
//Comment form re-arrangement
    comment_form( array(
    'comment_notes_before' => '',
    'comment_notes_after'  => '',
    'id_submit'            => 'entry-comment-submit',
    'label_submit'         => __( 'Submit' , '__x__' ),
    'title_reply'          => __( '<span>Leave a Comment</span>' , '__x__' ),
    'fields'               => array(
    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . get_comment_author()  . '" placeholder="' . __( 'Name *', '__x__' ) . ' ' . '" size="30"/>' .
    '</p>',
    'email'  =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email">' .

      '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="' .get_comment_author_email() . '" placeholder="' . __( 'Email *', '__x__' ) . ' ' . '" size="30"/>' .
    '</p>',
    'url'    =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url">' .

      '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . get_comment_author_url() . '" placeholder="' . __( 'URL', '__x__' ) . '" size="30" />' .
    '</p>'
),
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">' .
                     '</br>'.
                      $cs_print_smilies .
                     '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="4" placeholder="' . _x( 'Comment *', 'noun', '__x__' ) . '" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
                   '</p>'

) );
?>

    </div>
```

But with using above code I will have these PHP notices in my published posts, above the comments area:

> ```
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 46
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 97
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 97
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 296
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 296
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foo/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 309
> ```

While I know the problem is not inside of comment-template.php file.

How may I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

This notice comes because object `$comments` is null. So the `have_comments()` must wrap all the thing to be sure there are comments before using any property.

in your case :

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : 
 /* the code */
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was about calling the fields value containers which are arrays, so:

```
   get_comment_author()
```

should change to something like this:

```
   $commenter['comment_author']
```

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem when i had tried to change the default location of comment form input fields this error appears so first verify it and check the condition on comment template. Also try `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`